# How to disable chunking in WSO2 2.2 API Manager?

Tags: api, wso2-api-manager, wso2

How to disable the chunking of API in WSO2 API Manager version 2.2.0?

In 2.1 version, I was adding Mediator file to disable the chunking while creating an API and it was working. But in 2.2, it is not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="chunk-disable-sequence">
        <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" />
</sequence>
```

What is th issue with later version? Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Try following : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="disable-chunking" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
</sequence>

Comment: it is not working